# What is the best javascript obfuscator?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I am looking to use a javascript obfuscator. What are some of the most popular and what impact do they have on performance?

Comment: Although the issues raised by Robert Harvey may be more or less true, the answers here provide a list of obfuscators and is very useful.  Further, Mr. Harvey implies that this expert site can only answer simplistic questions and expert "opinion" and extended discussion is somehow a negative.  Would the question be acceptable if it was "Can I get a list of obsfuscators?"  Regards,  Dave H.

Comment: **DUPLICATE OF** ->>> **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscateprotect-javascript**

Comment: you can use http://jsobfuscator.byethost7.com/

Comment: The best obfuscator you'll ever find is a poor programmer who can't write readable, maintainable code 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yahoo has a pretty good one.  It's technically a minifier, but it does a nice job of obfuscating in the process.

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Comment: Compressed and obfuscated via YUI Compressor online for free here: http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

Comment: link no longer works

Comment: Here's an updated link: https://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/

Comment: Nowadays I'm surprised whenever I see yahoo.com is still working.

Answer (score 9):

Tested 8 different obfuscators (except www.javascriptobfuscator.com), and was amazed by how much they all suck. Ended up writing my own obfuscator using regular expressions. Enjoy:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> names = new Dictionary<string, string>();
static bool testing = false;
static string[] files1 = 
    @"a.js,b.js,c.js"
    .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, " ", "\t", "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
static string[] ignore_names = 
    @"sin,cos,order,min,max,join,round,pow,abs,PI,floor,random,index,http,
    __defineGetter__,__defineSetter__,indexOf,isPrototypeOf,length,clone,toString,split,clear,erase
    RECT,SIZE,Vect,VectInt,vectint,vect,int,double,canvasElement,text1,text2,text3,textSizeTester,target,Number
    number,TimeStep,images,solid,white,default,cursive,fantasy,".
  Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, " ", "\t", "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] extra_names = @"a,b,c".Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, " ", "\t", "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string src = @"C:\temp";
string dest1 = src + "\\all1.js";
string dest2 = src + "\\all2.js";

static void Main()
{
  File.Delete(dest1);
  File.Delete(dest2);
  foreach (string s in files1)
    File.AppendAllText(dest1, File.ReadAllText(src + "\\" + s) + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, Encoding.UTF8);

  string all = File.ReadAllText(dest1);
  int free_index = 0;

  foreach (string s in extra_names)
  {
    free_index++;
    string free_name = "" + (char)('A' + (free_index % 25)) + (char)('A' + ((free_index / 25) % 25));
    Debug.Assert(free_name != "AA");
    names.Add(s, free_name);
  }

  Regex reg1 = new Regex("(var |function |\\.prototype\\.)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)");

  int startat = 0;
  while (startat < all.Length)
  {
    Match match = reg1.Match(all, startat);
    if (!match.Success)
      break;

    string key = all.Substring(match.Groups[2].Index, match.Groups[2].Length);
    if (!ignore_names.Contains(key))
    {
      free_index++;
      string free_name = "" + (char)('A' + (free_index % 25)) + (char)('A' + ((free_index / 25) % 25));
      Debug.Assert(free_name != "AA");
      if (!names.ContainsKey(key))
        names.Add(key, testing ? key + free_name : free_name);
    }
    startat = match.Groups[0].Index + match.Groups[0].Length;
  }

  Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"/\*.*\*/", RegexOptions.Multiline);
  Regex reg3 = new Regex("([^:\\\\])//.*\r\n");
  Regex reg4 = new Regex("([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)");
  Regex reg5 = new Regex("(\r\n)*[ \t]+");
  Regex reg6 = new Regex("(\r\n)+");
  all = reg2.Replace(all, eval2);
  all = reg3.Replace(all, eval3);
  all = reg4.Replace(all, eval4);
  all = reg5.Replace(all, eval5);
  all = reg6.Replace(all, eval6);
  File.WriteAllText(dest2, all);
}

public static string eval4(Match match)
{
  return names.ContainsKey(match.Groups[1].Value) ? names[match.Groups[1].Value] : match.Groups[0].Value;
}
public static string eval5(Match match)
{
  return string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[1].Value) ? " " : Environment.NewLine;
}
public static string eval6(Match match)
{
  return Environment.NewLine;
}
public static string eval2(Match match)
{
  return " ";
}
public static string eval3(Match match)
{
  return match.Groups[1].Value + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: Why do "they all suck"? What issue does your code solve?

Comment: @frenchie Well, for one, paste obfuscated javascript generated with those "sucky" obfuscators in to the JavaScript beautifier at http://jsbeautifier.org/ and watch it be un-obfuscated instantly.

Comment: @AareP, can you provide some sample transformations?

Comment: Not all of them. JScrambler for one is not.

Comment: This code replaces characters INSIDE strings.

Comment: This is very cool thanks for sharing. How can I use this? It looks like C++ but it doesn't have the includes.

Answer (score 5):

Well, google brought up this as the first link:

http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com

But I wonder what good obfuscation of javascript does. Whatever it is you're doing in javascript that needs obfuscation should probably be done server-side anyway, right?

Comment: Of all I've seen, this is perhaps the best obfuscator. Although I haven't tried JScrambler.

Comment: @AStackOverflowUser  JScrambler guys are freaky, they require you to upload your code and in my opinion it's over priced. That said JScrambler has the BEST JS protection

Answer (score 2):

I've never used obfuscator in production, but I've tested [JavaScript Utility](http://jsutility.pjoneil.net/) and it seems pretty good.

As for the performance, obfuscated code must be unpacked on the fly **each time** the page is loaded. Might not be a problem for small scripts, but the unpacking time will be significant with bigger files. On the other hand, minified code is directly executable by the browser.

Some obfuscators might produce output that does not run in older or less common browsers. You should test very carefully with the browsers you plan to support.

Comment: Obfuscators don't require any code unpacking.  Other schemes for minimizing the code might require that, but obfsucation by itself does not.

Comment: I agree that I got obfuscation and packing mixed up here. Packing is a common approach to obfuscate JS, but its main purpose is to decrease the size of the script file.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the [JavaScript Compressor](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) written by Dean Edwards.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to say Hackvertor (disclaimed I wrote it) it's free and it supports tag based conversion. Check out the example:-

http://www.businessinfo.co.uk/labs/hackvertor/hackvertor.php#PEBoYXNlZ2F3YV83KCKqwMHCw8TGyMnKy8zNzs%2FQ0dLT1NXW2Nna29zd3t%2Fg4eLj5OXm5%2Bjp6uvs7e7v8PHy8%2FT19vj5%2Bvv8%2Ff4kXyIpPmFsZXJ0KCJJJ2Qgc2F5IEhhY2t2ZXJ0b3IiKTxAL2hhc2VnYXdhXzc%2B

Comment: Does anyone know how to use this? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Packer with base62

http://dean.edwards.name/packer/
https://github.com/jcoglan/packr <= ruby version

Comment: Try pasting obfuscated code generated with this into http://jsbeautifier.org/ and see it rewritten like the original.