# JavaScript for online quiz?

Tags: javascript

Maybe a noob question, but I am really confused.
I'm trying to make an online quiz, where user has to choose between 4 possible answers. But I got stuck, well, because 1 question is really bothering me. So:
I have a JavaScript function which changes background color of a button and disables it, when user clicks on the wrong answer. And the right answer button (submit) calls for non-existent function, just to confuse people, if they decide to take a quick look at the source code. Everything went great, but then I started to think. What if user decides to take a deeper look at my source code? He would be able to see my JavaScript functions and, well, he could probably figure out the right answer without really playing. 
Is there any way I could hide the source (as I understand, it's not possible with JavaScript), but maybe I could use something else? What are other developers using in these situations? Any suggestions? :)

Comment: "Everything went great, but then I started to think" — BIG mistake.

Comment: That's the nature of the web. You can obfuscate the code (not recommended), or minify the code.

Comment: If you want to keep people from seeing the correct answers, they need to not be part of the embedded source code, in which case all validation and checking will need to be handled server-side asynchronously with AJAX callbacks (or something equally "secure")

Comment: Great details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6869371/138088

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most Secure Method for Using Javascript To Check Quiz Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781627/most-secure-method-for-using-javascript-to-check-quiz-answers). Also related: [javascript security concern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12864537/1048572) on [game timing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12861419/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to be really safe, you have to do it on the server side (e.g. PHP). What you could possibly do to make it more difficult for cheaters is to obfuscate your javascript code by one of the various js obfuscators like [this one](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/) which can never bring full security.

Comment: Obfuscation (IMO) protects the logic more than the data itself... Never-the-less, it *is* one more hurdle for a devious user to get over - and in that sense, helps the OP. +1

Comment: Thank you! I think this will do it.

Answer (score 5):

The reason users can cheat is because the answer is in the JavaScript code.

Solution: **Don't put the answer in the JavaScript code**. Keep it on a server instead.

Something like this: Whenever the user changes their answer to the question...

1. JavaScript sends answer to server.
2. Server replies with YES or NO.
3. JavaScript displays reply to user.

The user never sees the answer, only whether it was true or false.

**tl;dr** Learn AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **good question** and one that every web developer should be asking themselves...

This is a major problem that we as web developers face daily. Our JavaScript is view able and sometimes even editable. Trust NOTHING that comes from the client!

What I usually do is

1. Generate some type of unique hash **on the server**
2. Embed this hash into the HTML and JavaScript.
3. Send this hash along with any request to the server.
4. Validate the hash on the server by recreating the hash again and making sure it matches the hash that was sent.

The hash could be a concatenation of the item's id, a session id, some salt and any other identifiable piece of data that you can reconstruct to validate the request.

Comment: Huh? Surely any JavaScript that generates hashes can be manipulated by the client. Whatever validating hash you're getting from the client is useless from a security perspective.

Comment: @aku - That is not what I meant. The hash is generated on the server, embedded into the JS and sent back to be validated on the server. I've edited my answer to put some more emphasis on the process. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

To complete the other answers, providing how learning how to set up a server could cost you a few days, I'll shortcut you a 5-min guide to setting a simple node.js server that will hide your answer.

Install node.js.

Create a file called `server.js` with the contents below.

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();
app.get("first_answer",function(req,res){
   res.send("b");
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Open the terminal, type

```
npm install express
cd path_to_the_folder_you_placed_the_file
node server.js
```

This will install the express.js module and run the server.

Now, on your site, using jQuery, just request the answer from the server. Example using jQuery:

```
var user_answer = ...
$.get("http://localhost:8080/first_answer",function(answer){
    if (answer == user_answer)
        alert("you got it right!");
});
```

For more complex examples and best use of the server, just read on `express.js` documentation. (;