# How to hide/encode the JavaScript code in a Bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet, and i want to hide/encode the JavaScript code within, something like a compiled code, so that the original code wont be available for the users of the bookmarklet;

Can i do this, and if yes, how ?

Comment: Not really - you can obfuscate it, though. But why is this tagged `php`?

Comment: the bookmarklet was developed under yii mvc, and it uses php, html, js

Comment: this is what i mean, obfuscate ... and is this the only method ?

Comment: yes. You can't really compile JavaScript code. You'd have to build a browser extension to have a compiled executable. Re obfuscating, look for `javascript obfuscation`

Comment: See e.g. [What is the best javascript obfuscator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/522064)

Comment: Also worth reading [Javascript library: to obfuscate or not to obfuscate - that is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2862470)

Comment: just wondering, what is your final goal for bookmarklet code obfuscation?

Comment: becauuse my bookmarklet is part of a online store combined with artificial intelligence, i need to encode the js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this site can help you: http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/

About it:

> Free Javascript Obfuscator is a professional tool for obfuscation of
>   javascript. It Converts JavaScript source code into **scrambled** and
>   completely **unreadable** form, preventing it from analysing and theft.

I gave it this input test:

```
alert("Hello World")
```

Output:

```
var _0x7d3e=["\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20\x57\x6F\x72\x6C\x64"];alert(_0x7d3e[0]);
```

You can test it in your Firefox Scratchpad (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>) or in Google Chrome console (<kbd>F12</kbd>).

Comment: This is from [About Page](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx). I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Meaning that would take someone about 2 seconds to decode. As obfuscatiors go, (and this is a fools errand anyway) it's not a very good one.